# How to make sliding screens without using tabs?

Tags: java, android, tabs, fullscreen

I want to use the sliding screens, but a fullscreen, without the tabs appearing, how to do this in android studio?

Comment: are you looking for view pager ?

Comment: There are `ViewPager` , `RecyclerView` and `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: Show your work, and  question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Am not quite sure what you are looking for but try the code below

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initUI();
}

/**
 * method to initialize our views
 */
public void initUI() {

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


/**
 * ViewPagerAdapter 
 */
private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int num) {

        Fragment frag=null;
        switch (num) {
            case 0:
                frag = new Fragment1();
                break;

            case 1:
                frag = new Fragment2();
                break;

            case 2:
                frag = new Fragment3();
                break;
        }
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

More reference [here](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/android-viewpager-simple-tutorial-sliding-screens/)